# Fluent Nhibernate and MySql not playing well together

Tags: mysql, nhibernate

What references are necessary to have fluent nhibernate work with mysql.  I have downloaded the latest version (6.0.3.0) of the mysql connector, but it is still throwing exceptions related to the mysql driver.

Here is the exception:

{"Could not create the driver from NHibernate.Driver.MySqlDataDriver, NHibernate, Version=2.0.1.4000, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4."}

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience you need to have your MySQL reference set to 'Copy Local' true (i.e. the DLL is copied to your bin folder) to get NHibernate to work with MySQL at all. Have you done that?